# Why does Function.__proto__ return something different than other prototypes?

Tags: javascript, prototype

If you try to print out the `__proto__` property of a regular object, say `{}.__proto__` or `foo.__proto__`, you get `[object object]`; this `[object object]` is the prototype of another object. However, if you try to print out the `__proto__` property of any function, it gives you `function () { [native code] }`. Why is that ? Shouldn't it return the prototype of the object that `Function` inherits from, which should be an object instead of another function (like `function(){native code]}`) ? How is it possible that the `__proto__` of a function is another function and not an object, like other prototypes ?

*i know that Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) should be used instead of **proto**, but i used that instead because it is shorter.

If someone explained the above to me, i would be grateful as well. And if you have any confusions regarding my question, please ask in the comments instead of downvoting.

Comment: How do you print? There might be type conversion going on...

Comment: `document.write()` in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause

```
Function.prototype.toString()
```

will return

```
"function (){ [native code] }"
```

The Function.prototype is an object, but as you print it, its typecasted to a string, and as the prototype implements the behaviour of functions:

```
function(){}.toString()
```

it will print being a function even if it isnt.

```
function(){}
 .__proto__ // Function.prototype
 .__proto__ // Object.prototype
 .toString() // "[Object object]
```

---

Maybe more imaginable:

```
class Human {
  toString(){
    return "Im a Human";
  }
}

console.log( 
(new Human).__proto__
);
//the Human.prototype tells you that it is a Human, however its just a class.
```

Comment: Well, why is that ? Why doesn't it return `[object object]` like others ? What does this mean ?

Comment: @taurus cause the function.prototype defined the behaviour of a function. Thats why it behaves like a function unlike it isnt

Comment: So `Function.prototype` is just a function ? Could you elaborate more ? Sorry but this is really confusing. On an entirely different note, how can `Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype` evaluate to `true` ? Doesn't this mean that `Function` is an instance of `Function` ?

Comment: @taurus no its an object. And yes every `function(){} instanceof Function`

Comment: yes but why is `Function` itself an instance of `Function` ? Isn't that sort of like saying a child is his own father ? To me it's like a paradox.

Comment: @taurus yes thats paradox. *Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype*

Comment: Constructors are functions, why does that surprise you?

Comment: @Jonasw so what the hell is happening behind the scenes ? does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: @taurus yes shure. Which curtain should i open?

Comment: @Jonasw any curtain that could remove a tiny bit of my confusion would do. Why is it an instance of itself ? Is it just like that ?

Comment: @Jonasw is it simply something like this: `function x() {}
 x.__proto__ = x.prototype;` ?

Comment: @taurus yes, both `__proto__` and `prototype` refer to the same object

Comment: @Jonasw Great! Wanna talk about `Object`s being instances of `Function`s and `Function`s being `Object`s ? #confusedashell

Comment: @taurus and how does that help you? Yes you can do `do { a = (a || {}).__proto__; } while(Infinity)`

Comment: @Jonasw To be more specific, i was talking about `Object instanceof Function` and `Function instanceof Object` both returning true.

Comment: @taurus yes cause `Object` and `Function` are both functions, and functions are objects. ;)

Comment: @Jonasw then what is the root Javascript object ? Function, object, or both ? Is there a way to create an object that does not involve this `Object` function ?

Comment: @taurus `Object.create(null)` returns an object that does not inherit the `Object.prototype`  . And everything in javascript is an object, and nearly everything is an `instanceof Object` . Functions are objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154022/discussion-between-taurus-and-jonas-w).

Comment: The problem was i had not included `toString()` in the equation, which turned a rather simple overlooked thing into a plethora of confusion inside my head.

Comment: Why does Function.prototype in the  chrome console give "native code" back when Object.prototype gives back the prototype as an object literal back

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, calling a constructor function with `var o = new f()` creates a new object, and
sets `o.__proto__` to `f.Prototype`. Same as:

```
new Array().__proto__ == Array.prototype // true
new Number().__proto__ == Number.prototype // true
```

or:

```
[].__proto__ == Array.prototype // true
(5).__proto__ == Number.prototype // true
```

`Function` is a constructor function, so creating a function with `new Function()` sets its prototype to `Function.prototype`:

```
new Function().__proto__ === Function.prototype // true
```

or:

```
(function() {}).__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
```

All functions have this same prototype, including constructor functions. So:

```
Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
Array.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
Number.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
```

`Function.prototype` defines the default behavior of functions, that all functions inherit from, including the ability to call it, so it acts as a function itself:

```
Function.prototype() // undefined
(new Function())() // undefined
```

Comment: About the comment you added to that other answer about by-value and by-reference, the accepted answer essentially proves what is stated in the David Flanagan article.

Comment: better to use  Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype is true!

Answer (score 0):

All the 'uppercase' constructor functions' _ *proto* _ will refer to Function. prototype or Function._ *proto* _(they refer to the same object) which is function () { [native code] } you get.